# need to drop pin at two places... current location and events locations

Tags: iphone

I need help on this .... drop the pins.

current location.... pin drop.... with blue....
Event location :locations latitude:53.373812...longitude 4.890951 with red pin.

I did like this:

```
@interface AddressAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

    NSString *mTitle;
    NSString *mSubTitle;

//  CLLocationManager *locationManager;
//  CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
@end
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>  {

    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;    
    AddressAnnotation *addAnnotation;
    NSString *address;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}
+(MapViewController *)sharedInstance;
-(void)start;
-(void)stop;
-(BOOL)locationKnown;
@property(nonatomic,retain)CLLocation *currentLocation;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *address;
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation;
-(void)showAddress;

@end
```

//Implementation file.

```
#import "MapViewController.h"



@implementation AddressAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate;
//@synthesize currentLocation;

- (NSString *)subtitle{
    //return @"Sub Title";
    return @"Event";
}
- (NSString *)title{
    //return @"Title";
    return @"Location ";
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c{
    coordinate=c;
    //NSLog(@"%f,%f",c.latitude,c.longitude);
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize address;
@synthesize currentLocation;

static MapViewController *sharedInstance;

+(MapViewController *)sharedInstance{
    @synchronized (self)
    {
        if (!sharedInstance) 
            [[MapViewController alloc]init];
        }
    return sharedInstance;
}
+(id)alloc{
    @synchronized(self){
        NSAssert(sharedInstance==nil,"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton LocationController."); 
        sharedInstance = [super alloc];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
-(id)init{
    if(self==[super init]){
        self.currentLocation=[[CLLocation alloc]init];
        locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        locationManager.delegate=self;
        [self start];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)start{
    NSLog(@"Start");
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
-(void)stop{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
-(BOOL)locationKnown{
    if (round(currentLocation.speed)==-1) 
        return NO;
        else return YES;

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    if (abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]])<120){
        self.currentLocation=newLocation;
    }
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *alert;
    alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
} 
        // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"Map-View";
    [self addressLocation];
    [self showAddress];
    NSLog(@"address is %@",address);

}

-(void)showAddress{ 

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];
    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;

    if(addAnnotation != nil) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
        [addAnnotation release];
        addAnnotation = nil;
    }

    addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    [mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];

}


-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 

   [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        //Show error
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;

    return location;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annView.animatesDrop=YES;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [address release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Please help me out...

thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

Showing user current location is simple.

```
-(void)start{
    NSLog(@"Start");
     mapView.showsUserLocation=YES; //This will show the current location as blue dot in your mapview
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
-(void)stop{
     mapView.showsUserLocation=NO;
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

In your viewForAnnotation Delegate

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) 
{
    // This code will execute when the current location is called.
    return nil;
}
else
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annView.animatesDrop=YES;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}
```

Comment: In if condition do i need to call for other pin for my current location with different color its work sir........ MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]    initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    annView.animatesDrop=YES;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;

Comment: i tested this application on my device....It point only my destination locatioin... do any one help me out what to do...when my view loaded i need to point my current location... and i need to drop pin at destination too.. help me out @thanks in advance

Comment: just see my code above. when you set showsUserLocation to YES the os will take care of annotating a blue dot showing the user current location. dont create any annoatation views inside the if condition. simply return nil there.

Comment: @build succeeded i cant see the pin in simulator on current location when i done with that. i passed   - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
 if (annotation==mapView.userLocation) {
 return nil;
   //
}
else {
  
 MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
 annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
 annView.animatesDrop=YES;
 annView.canShowCallout = YES;
 annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
 return annView;
}


 
}

Comment: yeap... in view did load i set.. mapview.showsUserLocation=Yes.

Comment: my current location is hyderabad... destination location is amsterdam..  I am viewing amsterdam with red color pin... now when i scroll to hyderabad... its not showing the blue pin.

Comment: I think i m out. See this link  http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=759744